# JavaFX: passing data between Controllers is always null

Tags: javafx

I want to apologize in advance, as this is discussed previously in ["Passing Parameters Directly From the Caller to the Controller"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml), but I followed every possible solution I found and still I can't get it work.

I have difficulty in passing a parameter  from one controller to another.

Specifically:

**LoginController** passes `username` to **MainController**.

When I click login button **LoginController** sets the `username` to the **MainController**. But, when Main.fxml is loaded `username` is NULL.

As trying to figure it out, I would like to ask:

1. When **MainController** `initialize()` method gets called? I suppose by the time **LoginController** calls `st.show();` ?
2. If the previous is correct, then why **MainController** `username` is NULL, since we have already set its value in **LoginController** using `mainController.setUsername(username)` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code.

**LoginController.java**

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {
    ...
    @FXML TextField username;

    @FXML public void actionLoginButton() {
        ...
        Stage st = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Region root = (Region) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        st.setScene(scene);

        MainController mainController = loader.<MainController>getController();
        mainController.setUsername(username.getText());

        st.show();
    }
    ...
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
    ...
    String username;

    @FXML Label lblWelcomeUser;

    public void setUsername(String usrname) {
        this.username = usrname;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...    
        lblWelcomeUser.setText("Welcome, " + this.username);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the timing of your call to set `username`.

The `initialize()` method of `MainController` is called **during** the execution of the following statement:

```
Region root = (Region) loader.load();
```

At this time, the `username` field in `MainController` is null and so its value is reported as null in the welcome message.  Your call to `setUsername()` occurs after the `MainController.initialize()` method has completed.

In general, the `initialize()` method of controller classes loaded with the FXML loader should never try to do anything with instance fields whose values have not been injected by the FXML loader.  These instance fields will not have been initialized at the time that the `initialize()` method is invoked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The only solution I could figure out is to create a new User class and to store data in it. But, this is "too much" for storing only one parameter.

So, for cases like this use static fields instead?

Comment: Just change your `setUsername(String usrName)` to call `lblWelcomeUser.setText("Welcome, "+usrName);`.

Comment: @James_D This was so obvious that I couldn't see it at all ! Just one minor change and voila! I've been trying this the whole day. I'm really embarrassed. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: if this answer helped you with your problem, please check it as the accepted answer.