# Cant pass data between JavaFX controllers

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, fxml

I am trying to pass data between controllers of differen FXML scenes. But I am not able to pass data to another controller. 
This is my first controller.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

Session session;

private static Stage myStage;

@FXML
private Button button;

@FXML
private TextField txtAd;

@FXML
private TextField txtSifre;

@FXML
void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Userss where ad = :code and sifre = :sifre");
        query.setParameter("code", txtAd.getText().trim());
        query.setParameter("sifre", txtSifre.getText().trim());
        if (query.list().size() == 1) {

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Giriş");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            String s = "This is an example of JavaFX 8 Dialogs... ";
            alert.setContentText(s);
            alert.showAndWait();

        }


        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    } finally {

        try {
            session.close();

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDevam.fxml"));
            DevamController devamController = loader.getController();
            devamController.as("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            AnchorPane login = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(login);

            myStage.setTitle("asd");
            myStage.setScene(scene);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

static void setStage(Stage stage) {
    myStage = stage;
}
```

}

And this is the second controller.

```
 public class DevamController implements Initializable {

String as ;


@FXML
private Label lblAd;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO

    lblAd.setText(as);
}    

public void as (String a){
   as = a;
}
```

}

I get NullPointerException at this line:

```
 devamController.as("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
```

I have tried this and it is not working :
[JavaFX: passing data between Controllers is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360795/javafx-passing-data-between-controllers-is-always-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller is loaded from the FXML file (since that is where it is defined, with `fx:controller`), so it will be null until you load the FXML with `loader.load()`. Just switch the order:

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDevam.fxml"));
        AnchorPane login = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        DevamController devamController = loader.getController();
        devamController.as("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
```

You will need to update the label in your `as()` method, since `initialize()` will already have been executed.

Comment: I have already seen you answer in the other link in comments. But I couldnt understand. I m trying to do this for hours. It worked now. Thanks alot.